# Why didn't Voldemort hide his Horcruxes using Fidelius Charm?

Tags: harry-potter, character-motivation, fidelius-charm

I have seen many discussions here about locations where Voldemort hid his Horcruxes. The fans settle down with this: Voldemort chose those locations where he himself could easily reach.

Why didn't Voldemort just vanish his Horcruxes using Fidelius Charm and became *Secret Keeper* himself? This way only and only he could reach it (making him 100% immortal). And, there's no flaw to it.

Comment: Because he didn't, and it would have made for a boring story. That's it. There are an almost infinite number of "Why didn't this character do this thing in this circumstance?" questions you could ask, the answer is generally "Because it's crap for the plot."

Comment: Yes, that is a plot hole. There is no answer, because JK Rowling wasn't very detail-oriented when it came to plot holes.

Comment: See also: [Why didn't Voldemort collect the horcruxes after he was resurrected?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7312/5184), [Why Didn't Voldemort Monitor His Horcruxes?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7315/5184), [Why didn't Voldemort keep the Horcruxes with him?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/59163/5184), and well... [every question about why Voldemort didn't do something](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22why+didn%27t+voldemort%22+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: Can you becaem Secret Keeper by yourself? I thought it must always be another person you trust. Trust is alien to Voldemort, so...

Comment: @FolksLord If you have canon backup, turn that into answer.

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe it's a place for a new question

Comment: I'm voting to reopen because I suspect the answer will lie in the wording of Fidelius: "inside a single, living soul"

Comment: I am certain we don't know all there is to know about this charm. Could you put yourself under said Charm, essentially rendering yourself invisible? Can you make yourself Secret Keeper, or wouldn't that kind of short circuit the spell?

Comment: I don't see a reason why this question couldn't have a fact-based answer.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist this should be the answer for almost every Harry Potter question.

Comment: The problem with questions like this is that the exact rules for the Fidelius Charm are unknown - for all we know, he _couldn't_ have done it, or perhaps would've needed to confide in at least another person due to some rule of how it works.

Answer (score 13):

To simply put, "because Voldemort likes grandeur", as stated by Dumbledore to Harry
The same reason he wouldn't make his horcruxes ordinary objects that would blend into the environment and would be practically impossible to detect, such as empty potion bottles or grains of sand on the beach

A cave full of inferi and a bunch of dark magic protecting  the locket, with the locket being buried deep in a potion that can only be drunk through a magical flask, inside a cave which symbolised one of the first instances of him showing his magical superiority over muggles seems much grander than just hiding it using a spell that makes it undetectable to anyone else. Furthermore, even if he did use the Fidelius Charm, it might be possible for someone like Dumbledore to detect where Voldemort hid it, even if he couldn't actually find it. In the last book while Harry, Ron and Hermione are on the run, Voldemort's followers know where the House of Black was, even if they could not go in themselves to catch him.

Similarly we can understand why he would choose the other hiding places for his horcruxes. Let's go through them one by one:

1. Ravenclaw's diadem at Hogwarts Castle:  It can't get any grander than that.
2. Hufflepuff's cup at Gringotts : We don't know for sure whether he chose Gringotts for the cup, but he entrusted it to Bellatrix so we can assume that he knew she would chose a location worthy of such a valuable object. Or he might have just told her to keep it in a nice safe place, and Gringotts might be the nicest safest place she could think of, which also holds her family's fortunes gathered through generations (why she didn't hide it using the Fidelius Charm is anybody's guess, but then again, she probably did not know how valuable an item it was, just like Malfoy didn't. She just knew Voldemort told her to keep it in a safe place, and she did)
3. The diary : Similar to Hufflepuff's cup he had entrusted the diary to one of his most loyal followers. Too bad Malfoy tried to use it for his own gain once he thought Voldemort had gone forever, but that's not Voldemort's fault.
4. Peverrel Ring in the Gaunt House: This one does not hold much grandeur I admit, but it was important to Voldemort, kind of like the diary was. The diary was not a historical object, yet Voldemort used it as one of his horcruxes because of it's personal value to him. In a similar way, he used the Gaunt House to hold the ring because the place had a personal value for him. It was the house of his ancestors, a pureblood line descended from Slytherin.

The remaining parts of his soul are in the snake, Harry and Voldemort himself, but I think it is obvious why they aren't hidden in grand locations.

Comment: they know where the house of the black's is, because the secret keeper (dumbledore) died...

Comment: @Armin After a secret keeper die, the secret isn't just out flying open. If Dumbledore didn't choose to reveal this secret to anyone, the secret would remain secret forever.

Answer (score 12):

Since Harry can see into Voldemort's mind (and indeed does see the Horcrux locations when V is checking up on them) , "no flaw to it" doesn't seem accurate. I'm pretty sure the Fidelius charm wouldn't stop Harry, since he's got a part of the Secret Keeper within him.

Now, he might not be *aware* of this as a flaw, but he's not even aware that anybody *knows* about his Horcruxes; he sees them as fool-proof already. Voldemort being arrogant and unaware of his own flaws is a constant theme in the series. Putting a Fidelius Charm on his toys goes counter to that.

Comment: That's a fascinating premise, there.

Comment: And isn't it that using fidelius you hide your secret in your living soul. Propaply Voldemort can't do this anymore as he does not have a complete, unscared soul.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry but i'm going to commit necromancy on this post because there is a very good reason nobody has mentioned

> "an immensely complex spell ... involving the magical concealment of a secret inside **a** living soul. The information is hidden inside the chosen person, or Secret-Keeper, and is henceforth impossible to find -- unless, of course, the Secret-Keeper chooses to divulge it." (PoA pg 205/152)

The key word here is 'a' as in singular from a language point of view. If he split his soul then every piece combined is the keeper so his main body would also have to be inside the charm to (and all the other pieces), he would have to be inside the charm himself with all the other pieces to work.

He cant carry out his mission by hiding inside the charm, the wording means that all the pieces are secret keepers combined so if even a single piece dies the spell is broken - you cant have a full cake with even 1% missing.

If the secret keeper dies the charm still remains intact if he hasn't told anyone, but the whole soul is needed for the charm to work, if one part dies he is both alive and dead at the same time and so the soul is no longer complete - which means the charm has to break (not be lost forever).

The spell is dependent on a complete soul that is either alive or dead, not in limbo with UK English the word 'a' changes everything. Its singular so no part could die without breaking it, it can only be hidden forever if all the pieces die (which defeats the point) or if ALL the pieces remain alive

This may not be what JK intended but she is usually good with the wording (her math may be bad, and she created some plot holes but her wording has always been literal and exact)

A spell can either work or fail but it never **semi** works, the closest we get is the cruciatus curse on Bellatrix, even that was due to him not really wanting to hurt her, the spell worked it just didn't have much strength as he didn't want to. The volume was dialed down but it did work

Comment: No need to apologise for adding a good answer to an old post! I'm not sure I agree with your conclusions, though. He wouldn't have needed to hide inside the charm like the Potters did as he was protecting his Horcrux, not anyone else. The only way anyone could discover where the Horcrux was would be if he told them or if someone travelled with him to the location with side-along Apparition.

Comment: By spitting your soul it creates a paradox, all has to be safe or nothing is. So you can either kill yourself (and all horcruxes) to keep the secret lost forever or never let any piece die including the main body (which means hiding in a safe place like inside the charm). The spell is either working or it isn't, it cant be both at the same time, so you have the same problem as someone without horcruxes, (die or hide forever in the safest place possible)