# Immortality loop-hole - Hide horcrux inside Fidelus-protected building/place

Tags: harry-potter, fidelius-charm

According to canon, is there anything preventing one from concealing one's Horcrux inside a building/place and then simply protecting it with the Fidelius charm, with one being the one and only secret-keeper?

It seems huge flaw to me that V allowed his Horcruxes to be found (and eventually destroyed) that easily. Especially the ring and locket. They were both in some kind of rooms. Using the Fidelius charm would make them simply unobtainable, thus making big V REALLY immortal.

Comment: Same question previously closed as "opinion-based"; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/63784/why-didnt-voldemort-hide-his-horcruxes-using-fidelius-charm/63786#63786

Comment: A Fidelius'ed location may not necessarily be impossible to reach. Even if this question is a duplicate, it's probably not of that one.

Comment: You could just burn the whole street down with Fiendfyre to destroy such a Horcrux.

Comment: @user13267 - A Fidelius location is supposedly impossible to reach for those not in on the secret. Which makes this at least a semi-dupe. Certainly it fits the bill of "opinion-based" which is what the first iteration of this question was closed for. If you feel that the close reason is incorrect, feel free to vote to reopen so that it can be reclosed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to cannon, no, there is nothing to prevent one from concealing one's horcruxes inside a building place then simply protecting it with the Fidelius Charm. In fact this has happened.

After Grimmauld Place was made the Order headquarters and Dumbledore put his Fidelius charm over it, Slytherins locket which was one of the horcruxes was still in there, making it a horcrux inside the boundaries of a Fidelius Charm, showing that it's not impossible

As for why Voldemort didn't do it, [please see here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/63786/13716).